# Java Action Listener Nested Loop

Tags: java

I am doing a battle ship game and I am new to the Java subject. I did a grid layout with a nested loop in order to create 100 JButtons, but I am experiencing difficulty in trying to add an action listener to all buttons. Is there any way of someone to give me a hand ?

I will post the code later on :)

cheers guys.

```
enter code here
 public Center_Panel() {
    this.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(10, 10));
    panel1.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        JButton button = new JButton(Integer.toString(i + + j));
        panel1.add(button);
        }
        //grid [i][j] = b;
    }

    this.add(panel1);

    JPanel panel2 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(10, 10));

    panel2.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        JButton button = new JButton(Integer.toString(i + + j));
        panel2.add(button);}
```

Comment: What difficulty are you having? What exactly is the issue?

Comment: You can add the listener when creating the buttons (while being in the loop). If you post some code, it will be easier to help you.

Comment: You want to add the same listener to all buttons? Also please add your code under your question so we can see what are you trying to do.

Comment: Btw. in your case (battle ship game) it seems useful to store your buttons inside a two dimensional array (JButton[][])

Answer (score 1):

Declare JButton out of for loop, then initial them in for loop.
you need to create an array for JButton, you'r assigning different strings to the same reference.

this code for creating JButton and add them to panel.

```
 JButton button[] = new JButton [100];
 int count = 0;
 for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
     for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        button[count] = new JButton(Integer.toString(i + + j));
        panel1.add(button);
        count++; 
        }
 }
```

this code to add them to action listener.

```
 for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++) {
    button[x].addActionListener(this);
 }
```